# Best (current) method to buy BTC in the UK?

Tags: transactions, exchanges

I'm in the UK and am desperately trying to get onto this Bitcoin bandwagon before the whole thing collapses, but it seems like there are no decent ways to buy from the UK. There is an international wire transfer, but Barclays charge £15-25 for wire transfers so it's incredibly inefficient.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why you want to invest in something you think will collapse, but I'd suggest taking a look at the wiki page: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Buying_bitcoins. Not knowing what transfer options your bank supports, I can't provide a specific recommendation, but you might find something workable there.

Comment: @BinaryMage Three words: [Greater fool theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_fool_theory)

Comment: Yeah I'm hoping to sell before the bubble bursts haha